# How to check for success event after executing a save() on a model

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using the following code to save additional properties to a model (answer model in this case)

```
selectMedia: =>
  # Post media to server
  @options.answer.id = @options.answer.get('_id')
  @options.answer.url = "/v1/answers/#{@options.answer.get('_id')}"

  @options.answer.save
    youtube_id: @options.media.get('vid')
    success: (result) =>

      $('.modal').html('')
      $('.modal').modal('toggle')
      @options.question_view.remove()
      @options.question_view.render()
    error: ->
      console.log("error")
```

I want to execute a set of commands only when the save is executed successfully.
I tried the code above but it is not working (although I checked that the data was indeed saved)

Please advise on how I can modify the code to check for the success event

Comment: This looks vaguely backbone-ish.  Are you using backbone?  If so, add it to the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `save` incorrectly. Backbone's [`save` takes separate attributes and options arguments](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save):

> **save** `model.save([attributes], [options])`
>   [...]
>   **save** accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash,

but you're only passing one hash. You need to call it like this:

```
@options.answer.save { youtube_id: @options.media.get('vid') }
  success: (result) =>
    $('.modal').html('')
    $('.modal').modal('toggle')
    @options.question_view.remove()
    @options.question_view.render()
  error: ->
    console.log("error")
```

or perhaps like this if you really hate braces:

```
@options.answer.save 'youtube_id', @options.media.get('vid')
  success: (result) =>
    $('.modal').html('')
    $('.modal').modal('toggle')
    @options.question_view.remove()
    @options.question_view.render()
  error: ->
    console.log("error")
```

Comment: I've been trying to follow this, but whenever I added the -> after the function it isn't called. If I take the -> away from them though both the success and error functions are called. Do you know if that's a server problem or a client problem? The 500 Internal Error is returned as I'd expect...

Comment: @TomHammond: Hard to say what's going on without seeing exactly what you're doing. CoffeeScript's loose-ish syntax can be a curse.

Comment: Saving this for my arguments against CoffeeScript. Both versions of your answer have strange syntax (not your fault obviously).